# Project has triggered a break point - in microsoft visual studio

Tags: c++, exception

I am using microsoft visual studio and windows 10. This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class class1 {
    int* ptr;
    int nr;

public:
    class1()
    {

    }
    void setPtr(int* ptr, int nr)
    {
        this->nr = nr;
        this->ptr = new int(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
            this->ptr[i] = ptr[i];
        cout << ptr;
    }
};
int main()
{
    class1 obj;
    int v[] = { 1,2,3 };
    int nr = 3;
    obj.setPtr(v, nr);
}
```

I have no idea why it works on both phone an codeblocks but it crashes on visual. Am I doing something wrong? Our professor required us to use visual studio. Thanks so much! P.S.: I'm a beginner.

Comment: Have it break into the debugger then change your StackFrame in the debug toolbar of Visual Studio to your code to see the line of your code that was executing.

Comment: `new int(100);` allocates exactly 1 `int` and intiializes it with value `100`. Did you mean `new int[100];`?

Comment: ***I have no idea why it works on both phone an codeblocks but it crashes on visual. Am I doing something wrong? Our professor required us to use visual studio.*** It was undefined behavior. Unfortunately sometimes with UB your program appears to work when the program is broken like you saw in Code::Blocks. That is the worst behavior of undefined behavior as it makes you believe your broken code is correct.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen OP wants `new int[nr]` surely.  Amongst other things.